# Retrieve a mailchimp list via GET

Tags: get, mailchimp

I am trying to retrieve a MailChimp list.

I have an API Key and a List ID, and while I understand that I can use the MailChimp API wrapper to achieve this I prefer to avoid implementing it since I only need to do this one task.

When I enter in my browser:

```
https://us3.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/members?apikey=*****&id=******
```

I get a JSON result of my list - but it is limited to the first 25 subscribers.  I don't see anything in the MailChimp API documentation about submitting a GET request to retrieve a list.  Is it possible to do so? If so, how can I retrieve a full list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the best method is to use the MailChimp `list method` which "Exports/dumps members of a list and all of their associated details. This is a very similar to exporting via the web interface."

Read more at http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/list.func.php

Another option is to use API v1.3 `listMembers` function, more info here: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listmembers.func.php.  v1.3 is deprecated, but it still functions properly.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/members.php

Options are available via pagination.

You are supposed to POST the values in your request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I see something about `start`, but when I add a `&start=` to the URL nothing changes

Comment: Can you please share your complete request?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't since it's for someone else's list and I'm not at liberty to share their API Key publicly

Comment: I've just edited by answer that says you are supposed to POST values.